# image click redirecting to a URL, and then clicking on an image of the new URL to go back to main page

Tags: php, html

I am doing a photo gallery with php, and my main page is a gallery with all thumbnail images. If you click on any thumbnail, it will link to another page with the original size image (like google images does). I do that with an hyperlink that contains an image inside :

```
<a href='".$row['image']."' class='image' title='".$row['title']."'>"."<img   src=".$row['thumb']." class='thumb'/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a>
```

Then if the user is now in the redirected page showing the big image selected, how can I do it so that if the user clicks on top of the big size image then it will be redirected to the main page with all the thumbnails?

Comment: You can use javascript back to go to the previous page `window.history.back()`

Comment: I am not allowed to use any javascript (only php). Can I do so that the image inside the href instead of being image would be another href???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to link to a detail page using `<a href`, why are you not able to do the same from the detail page?

considering you are on listing page, say listing.php and images are listed from database. You can loop through the images as given below.

```
  <a href="detail-image.php?id=<?php echo $image_from_database['id'];?>" class='image' title="image title">  
    <img src="<?php echo $image_from_database['thumb'];?>" class='large'/>
  </a>
```

So, on clicking you will be redirected to detail-image.php where you can get the id using PHP $_GET/$_REQUEST

and then fetch the big image from database and show it. There you can do same to link to the listing page

```
<a href="listing.php" class='image' title="image title">  
  <img src="<?php echo $image_from_database['large_image'];?>" class='thumb'/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['image'];?>"class='image' title="<?php echo $row['title'];?>">

  <img src="<?php echo ['thumb'];?>" class='thumb'/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look I don't know exactly what's the problem,

but I think there wrong in your code,

must be like it,

```html
<a href="<?php echo $row['image'];?>"class='image' title="<?php echo $row['title'];?>">
  
  <img src="<?php echo ['thumb'];?>" class='thumb'/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
</a>
```

!! The page must be "Something.php"